# Call SQL Query from another SQL Server Query (Management Studio)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know this is redundant, but I'd like to Call Query from another Query.  I know I can just add it to first one, but the scripts are getting long and at times I don't want to run all of the queries.

I've been looking and my best guess is maybe just using command shell.  I was just wondering if there was another way.

```
Declare @CommandDos VarChar(150) = 'sqlcmd -E -S Server-i h:\SQL\SomeThing.sql'
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @CommandDos
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code re-use.
Perhaps use functions, i.e. put the query you want called into a function.

Functions can be Scalar, Table-valued, Deterministic, or Nondeterministic.

Comment: Ended up just using functions and Variable temp table.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can create stored procedures with the queries, then call them inside another one if needed.

What do you think about it?